# How to force a webpage to open in a particular IE version?

Tags: internet-explorer

How to **force** a webpage to open in a particular browser (IE 8, IE 9 or IE 10) and with **standards** (not quirks) mode in IE 10 browser?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the appropriate action here is to comment with the link to the possible duplicate. However, I need 49 more reputation to do that, so in the interest of expediency I believe this question has your answer: [What does <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-e). The non-emulate modes don't accept quirks.